# custom sorting v-data-table with strings values

Tags: string, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table, custom-sort

My goal is to be able to sort DEST or ASC the table. To do this, in the array 'tableItems' I get unformatted numbers, which I format to have the dot for thousands and the comma for decimals with the 'numericValues' method. This method returns numeric data, but in strings.

```
numericValues() {
    const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('de');

    this.tableItems.forEach((item) => {
      for (const key in item) {
        if (typeof item[key] === 'number') {
          const formattedValue = numberFormat.format(item[key]);

          item[key] = formattedValue;
        }
      }
    });
 }
```

I would like to be able to sort the table these strings but as if they were numbers. To do this, I have added the line ':custom-sort="customSort"' in my template.

The problem of having added the 'customSort' method, is that sort no longer works in my table, when I click on the headers

So, I show what I have tried to do with the method I add in custom-sort:

This is my template:

```
<v-data-table
          :headers="tableHeaders"
          :items="tableItems"
          :items-per-page="18"
          :search="search"
          class="elevation-1"
          :style="getTableHeight()"
          :custom-sort="customSort"
></v-data-table>
```

This is my method customSort:

```
customSort(tableItems: any[], index: number, isDescending: boolean): any[] {
    return tableItems.sort((a, b) => {
      console.log(a)
      const valueA = a;
      const valueB = b;

      if (typeof valueA === 'string' && typeof valueB === 'string') {
        const numA = Number(valueA);
        const numB = Number(valueB);

        if (!isNaN(numA) && !isNaN(numB)) {
          return isDescending ? numB - numA : numA - numB;
        }
      }

      return isDescending ? String(valueB).localeCompare(valueA) : String(valueA).localeCompare(valueB);
    });
}
```

Can anyone give me some advice on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the custom sort and `v-data-table` will sort according to the primitive data type. If these are `Number` - then they will be sorted numerically. You should format the values in the template only - not in the raw data. Simply use the corresponding slot for the given column.

Comment: Yes. Probably I have to delete the method 'numericValues', it will works. But I need the dots in the thousands and comma in decimals. If I use 'numericValues' I have String, but I need numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it as follows:

In the `<v-data-table`> component I added a `<template>` tag to customize the appearance and formatting of the data in the table.

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="tableHeaders"
    :items="tableItems"
    :items-per-page="18"
    :search="search"
    class="elevation-1"
    :style="getTableHeight()"
        >
        <template
          v-for="(headerItem, index) in tableHeaders"
          v-slot:[`item.${headerItem.value}`]="{ item }"
        >
          {{ headerItem.formatter ? headerItem.formatter(item[headerItem.value]) : item[headerItem.value] }}
        </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Finally, the method where it loaded the headers, added the formatting.

```
loadTableHeaders() {
    let aliases = [];
    aliases = this.$store.state.informes.dataInformes.get('aliases')?.filter((item: any) => item.endpoint === this.config.sources).sort((a: any, b: any) => (a.order < b.order ? -1 : 1));
    if (!aliases) {
      aliases = this.$store.state.informes.dataInformes.get(this.config.sources); // FIXME: Ordenar headers cuando no existan aliases
    }
    aliases.forEach((item: any) => {
      if (item.alias !== 'Nivel Territorial') {
        if ((informesStore.state.nivTerr !== 'CC.AA' && informesStore.state.nivTerr !== 'Nacional')
          || ((informesStore.state.nivTerr === 'CC.AA' || informesStore.state.nivTerr === 'Nacional') && item.alias !== 'Ámbito superior')) {
            this.tableHeaders.push({ text: item.alias, value: item.indicator, formatter: this.formatNumericValues });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  formatNumericValues(value: any) {
    if (typeof value === 'number' && !isNaN(value)) {
      return new Intl.NumberFormat('de').format(value);
    } else {
      return value; // Devuelve el valor sin formato para casos no numéricos
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

- The types of `customSort()` does not match that of  [`:custom-sort`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-custom-sort). Your `index` is declared as number, but it is actually a string array (`sortBy`), and your `isDescending` (`sortDesc`) is actually a boolean array. You could have just copied the declaration from the documentation...
- You logged the variable, so you are probably aware that the input to `sort()` is the whole object, not just the value. So when you assign the whole object to `valueA` and `valueB` respectively, none of the following comparisons will work. You need to extract the values using the props in `sortBy`.
- A number in a local format, like german `1.000,56`, cannot be transformed back to a number with `Number()`, you either need to parse it back or, preferably, keep the original number somewhere on your object and fall back to it during sorting.
- If you want to be able to sort by multiple values, you need to go through the `sortBy` array and compare each field until you get a non-zero value.